# On rank one torsion-free modules over local rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a local ring which is also an integral domain and $M$ be a rank one $A$-module. Denote by $k$ the residue field of $A$. Is $\dim M \otimes_A k \le 1$? If not, is there a known upper-bound for $\dim M \otimes_A k$?

Comment: Take $M=A\oplus (A/I)^n$, where $I$ is the maximal ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$B=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$,

$\mathfrak m=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\vartriangleleft_{\rm max} B$,

$A=B_{\mathfrak m}$,

$M=\mathfrak m_{\mathfrak m}$.

Then $K:=\mathrm{Frac} A\simeq k(x_1,\dots,x_n)\simeq M\otimes_A K$, so $M$ has rank one, but $\dim_k M\otimes k=n$.